# Xubuntu 20.04 asus x501u

Tags: amd-graphics

xfconf-query -c xfwm4 -p /general/vblank_mode -t string -s "glx" --create

I accidentally ran this command on my asus x501u . How can I return to the previous set-up?

Answer (score 0):

What the command did was set the channel of Xfwm4 property of `/general/vblank_mode` to `glx`.  The default setting for that is `auto`.  To set it back run the following command:

```
xfconf-query -c xfwm4 -p /general/vblank_mode -s auto
```

If you just run `xfconf-query -c xfwm4 -p /general/vblank_mode` it will show you what the setting is.

Hope this helps!